# Can i set -I ( Quoted Identifier ON ) for all scripts while running through Batch File?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

We have an Indexed view on one of our server instance and because of which my Batch file fails with Quoted Identifier being OFF issue. We manually made that ON inside script and that works perfect.

Now my Question is can we blanketly put -I ( Quoted Identifier = ON ) for all the files all the places. what all places this can cause a negative impact.

Comment: There should be no negative impact unless you have code that requires `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`.

Comment: I *assume* this is because of `sqlcmd`? If so, it might be worth considering switching to the "new" `sqlcmd` ("go-mssqldb"). This not only defaults to `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`, but it removes the `-I` option entirely.

Comment: ohh this is awesome "go-mssqldb" . will check this for sure and update .. Thanks a lot